# NAT / Port Forwarding with iptables firewall

Tags: iptables, firewall, nat, port-forwarding

I've got the following setup:

- firewall (iptables)

  - eth0 internal interface, 192.168.2.10
  - ppp0 external interface, public_ip (IP masquerading)
- server1 (192.168.2.11), service 1 (port 443)
- server2 (192.168.2.12), service 2 (port 443)
- client1 (192.168.2.21) ...

The firewall uses iptables for the following port forwarding rules:

- port 10000 -> 192.168.2.11:443
- port 10001 -> 192.168.2.12:443

This way, both services can be accessed from the internet using the public IP address and the ports 10001/10002. Unfortunately, client1 (and the other clients from the internal network) have to use the server IPs / ports: They can access the services using 192.168.2.11:443 and 192.168.2.12:443, but not using public_ip:10001/10002.

Maybe these problems are caused by the differences of the INPUT vs. the FORWARD chain in respect to the PREROUTING chain behaviour?

What can I do to change this situation? (I use "Arno's iptables firewall" script, if this helps.) Thanks a lot for any pointers.

**EDIT**: Here is the iptables configuration:

*iptables -nvL*

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 3 packets, 156 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
27362   13M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 482K   35M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED tcp dpts:1024:65535 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED udp dpts:1024:65535 
 1012 57505 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED 
 411K   31M HOST_BLOCK  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 409K   31M MAC_FILTER  all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MAC_FILTER  all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 411K   31M SPOOF_CHK  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1606  128K VALID_CHK  all  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1179  108K EXT_INPUT_CHAIN !icmp --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
   47  2340 EXT_INPUT_CHAIN  icmp --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW limit: avg 60/sec burst 100 
    0     0 EXT_ICMP_FLOOD_CHAIN  icmp --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
 409K   31M LAN_INPUT_CHAIN  all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 LAN_INPUT_CHAIN  all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Dropped INPUT packet: ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
98717 5423K TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      ppp+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
  41M   24G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state ESTABLISHED 
  187  9724 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED tcp dpts:1024:65535 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED udp dpts:1024:65535 
  271 17208 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED 
 125K 7842K HOST_BLOCK  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
78962 5186K MAC_FILTER  all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MAC_FILTER  all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
46489 2656K UPNP_FORWARD  all  --  ppp+   !ppp+   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 125K 7842K SPOOF_CHK  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
46489 2656K VALID_CHK  all  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   24 19108 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
78938 5167K LAN_INET_FORWARD_CHAIN  all  --  eth0   ppp+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 LAN_INET_FORWARD_CHAIN  all  --  tun0   ppp+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  698 41908 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp+   !ppp+   0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.38        tcp dpt:22 
  118  6564 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp+   !ppp+   0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.38        tcp dpt:443 
45546 2601K ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp+   !ppp+   0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.38        tcp dpt:8443 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp+   !ppp+   0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.38        tcp dpt:8899 
    7   364 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp+   !ppp+   0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.37        tcp dpt:22 
   15   788 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp+   !ppp+   0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.41        tcp dpt:443 
  105  5464 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp+   !ppp+   0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.45        tcp dpt:443 
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/min burst 3 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Dropped FORWARD packet: ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5403 packets, 1746K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   120 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      ppp+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
 424K   66M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state ESTABLISHED 
 437K   33M HOST_BLOCK  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 LOG        all  -f  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `FRAGMENTED PACKET (OUT): ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  -f  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 431K   31M EXT_OUTPUT_CHAIN  all  --  *      ppp+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DMZ_INET_FORWARD_CHAIN (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DMZ_INPUT_CHAIN (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DMZ_LAN_FORWARD_CHAIN (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain EXT_ICMP_FLOOD_CHAIN (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-request(ping) flood: ' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3 limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-unreachable flood: ' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 4 limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-source-quench flood: ' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 4 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 11 limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-time-exceeded flood: ' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 11 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 12 limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-param.-problem flood: ' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 12 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP(other) flood: ' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain EXT_INPUT_CHAIN (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:0 limit: avg 6/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `TCP port 0 OS fingerprint: ' 
    0     0 LOG        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:0 limit: avg 6/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `UDP port 0 OS fingerprint: ' 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:0 
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:0 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:0 limit: avg 6/hour burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `TCP source port 0: ' 
    0     0 LOG        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:0 limit: avg 6/hour burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `UDP source port 0: ' 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:0 
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:0 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:67 dpt:68 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1194 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:1194 
   31  1472 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 3/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-request: ' 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3 limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-unreachable: ' 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 4 limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-source-quench: ' 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 11 limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-time-exceeded: ' 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 12 limit: avg 12/hour burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-param.-problem: ' 
   53  8304 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpts:1024:65535 flags:!0x17/0x02 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Stealth scan (UNPRIV)?: ' 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpts:0:1023 flags:!0x17/0x02 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Stealth scan (PRIV)?: ' 
   85 17495 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 
  167  9228 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpts:0:1023 limit: avg 6/min burst 2 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Connection attempt (PRIV): ' 
   18  1193 LOG        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:0:1023 limit: avg 6/min burst 2 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Connection attempt (PRIV): ' 
  481 22848 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpts:1024:65535 limit: avg 6/min burst 2 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Connection attempt (UNPRIV): ' 
  172 44040 LOG        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:1024:65535 limit: avg 6/min burst 2 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Connection attempt (UNPRIV): ' 
  870 43344 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  224 47492 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   47  2340 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Other-IP connection attempt: ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain EXT_OUTPUT_CHAIN (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 431K   31M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain HOST_BLOCK (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INET_DMZ_FORWARD_CHAIN (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain LAN_INET_FORWARD_CHAIN (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  354 21240 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 20/sec burst 100 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 3/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-request: ' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
78584 5145K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LAN_INPUT_CHAIN (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
18741 1705K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 20/sec burst 100 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 3/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `ICMP-request: ' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
 390K   30M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain MAC_FILTER (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain RESERVED_NET_CHK (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Class A address: ' 
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Class B address: ' 
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Class C address: ' 
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       169.254.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Class M$ address: ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       169.254.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           

Chain SPOOF_CHK (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 488K   37M RETURN     all  --  eth0   *       192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  tun0   *       192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Spoofed packet: ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
48223 2834K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain UPNP_FORWARD (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain VALID_CHK (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x29 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Stealth XMAS scan: ' 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x37 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Stealth XMAS-PSH scan: ' 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Stealth XMAS-ALL scan: ' 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x01 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Stealth FIN scan: ' 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x06 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Stealth SYN/RST scan: ' 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x03/0x03 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Stealth SYN/FIN scan(?): ' 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x00 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Stealth Null scan: ' 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x29 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x37 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x01 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x06 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x03/0x03 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x00 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp option=64 limit: avg 3/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Bad TCP flag(64): ' 
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp option=128 limit: avg 3/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Bad TCP flag(128): ' 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp option=64 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp option=128 
  380 17623 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
    0     0 LOG        all  -f  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 3/min burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `Fragmented packet: ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  -f  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

*iptables -t nat -nvL*

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 428K packets, 31M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  697 41688 DNAT       tcp  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 to:192.168.2.38 
  118  6564 DNAT       tcp  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 to:192.168.2.38 
45542 2601K DNAT       tcp  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8443 to:192.168.2.38 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8899 to:192.168.2.38 
    7   364 DNAT       tcp  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:222 to:192.168.2.37:22 
   15   788 DNAT       tcp  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8082 to:192.168.2.41:443 
  105  5464 DNAT       tcp  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8083 to:192.168.2.45:443 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 479K packets, 34M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
49079 2610K TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      ppp+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
62427 3638K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ppp+    192.168.2.0/24      !192.168.2.0/24      

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 432K packets, 31M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Usually a DNAT rule checks for in interface (something like -i ppp0). Packets from client1 are received via eth0 so they don't match this rule. Theoretically you could remove that part (-i ppp0) but this could depend on other rules also. You should post your iptables rules for more help.

Comment: As Laurentiu said, please post the output of `iptables -nL` and `iptables -t nat -nL`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Indeed, the problem seems to be the same. But instead of using a consumer router, I have got an iptables firewall. Maybe it is possible to modify its configuration so that it handles the "hairpin NAT problem" better?

Comment: Found this link, maybe I have to do "source NAT": http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/253830/port-forwarding-with-iptables-is-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, the tip to search for "Hairpin NAT" helped me to solve my problem. For other interested users here are the rules that did the magic:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $EXT_IP -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination $OFFICE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $INT_NET -d $SERVER-p tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source $FIREWALL
```

Thanks for your help!