# Connect two servers with RJ-45 cable and iptables (without switch!)

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip, command-line-interface

I have two servers and server_1 is connected to INTERNET port (of server farm) at eth0. No switch.
They connected with cable from (server_1)eth1 -> (server_2)eth0 :

```
ifconfig of (server_1):
eth0    inet addr:199.203.51.24,
eth0:1  inet addr:212.235.19.200,
eth1 inet addr:10.0.0.1

ifconfig of (server_2):
eth0   inet addr:10.0.0.2
```

I want to connect server_2 to the internet with server_1, and get for him a static IP address from gatway at (server_1)eth0 .

tried using iptables at (server_2) like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.2 -j SNAT --to-source 212.235.19.203
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 212.235.19.203 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2
```

while the masking IP is 212.235.19.203 . that's works fine only for the world, but!! inside server_2 trying to ping 212.235.19.203 don't work!

Comment: That sounds like the common problem called hairpin NAT, [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/495823/nat-port-forwarding-with-iptables-firewall/496262#496262) might help.

Comment: Don't use MASQUERADE if your server has a static IP.

Answer (score 1):

Your `iptables` rules are broken in multiple ways. First of all, your `POSTROUTING` chain has two rules, but the first one matches every packet, so the second rule is never used.

Secondly, your `SNAT` and `MASQUERADE` rules should only be applied to packets leaving on `eth0`.

But since `212.235.19.203` is allocated to just one machine, you may be better off not using NAT at all.

An alternative solution is that you let the host currently assigned `10.0.0.2` actually have `212.235.19.203` assigned to the physical network interface (with netmask `255.255.255.255`). The gateway need a static route indicating that `212.235.19.203/32` is locally connected on `eth1`. Additionally, you can turn on `proxy_arp` on `eth0`.

With that combination you'll have the IP address truly routed to the intended host, which will make everything work better. You can avoid NAT rules for that IP, you can still filter traffic in the `FORWARDING` chain, if you want firewalling.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you tried the iptables at (server_1) instead of (server_2) as you said.

The problem here is that (server_2) doesn't know that it has to answer packets whose destination is 212.235.19.203.

One posible solution is to use the following in (server_2):

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 212.235.19.203 -j REDIRECT
```